# How to extract different values in array and save it in a Variable in postman

Tags: arrays, postman

How to extract site values "london" , "manchester " and "Birmingham" from an Array and save the values in an array variable in postman.

```
[
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "test",
    "site": "London", "Count":27,
    "active": false
  },
  {
    "Id": 2,
    "Name": "test1",
    "site": "Manchester",
    "Count": 412, "active": false
  },
  {
    "Id": 3,
    "Name": "test",
    "site": "Birmingham",
    "Count": 763,
    "active": true
  }
]
```

Comment: Post text, not images of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lodash` function to do it.

```js
const res = pm.response.json();
let sites = _.map(res, _.property("site"));

//or
let sites = _.map(res, "site"));
```